# Another express.js req.session not storing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, session-variables

I have been staring at the same SO questions/answers for too long.

I am trying to set my user ID in a req.session variable

here is my app.js stack

```
 /**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

 var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , User = require('./user-model')
  , path = require('path')
  , mysql = require('mysql');

app = express()
/**
 * Middleware.
 */
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'supercalafragalistic' }));
app.locals.pretty = true;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
...
app.get('/someRoute', routes.someRoute)
```

I have moved the app.router from top to bottom. Currently it is implied (I just deleted it as I stripped my code looking for error). I have exported app, included app in routes (also erased) . I added middleware. I am lost.....

here is my route stack

```
//routes/index.js
//requires
var  User = require('../user-model')
    ,qs = require('querystring')
    ,http = require('http')
    ,mysql = require('mysql')
    ,connection = mysql.createConnection({
         edited
    });

    /**
 * Set up application.
 */

    connection.connect(function(err){
        if(err) console.log('failed to connect to mysql because'+ err);
        else console.log('connected to mysql');
    })
```

I save the id in the login route:

```
//login processing route
exports.logIn = function(req, res, next){
    console.log('log in request from '+req.body.name);
    User.findOne({name:req.body.name}, function(err, user, next){

        if(err) return next(err);
        if(!user) return res.end();

//check password
        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) res.send('failed to find user');
            console.log(""+isMatch);
            if(isMatch){
                console.log(user._id.toString()+' user loggd in');
                //set session cookie
                req.session.loggedIn = user._id.toString();
                console.log('req.session.loggedIn set to :'+req.session.loggedIn );
                 res.send(user);

            }else {
               res.send('User not found try again'); 
            }

        });    
    });
```

However, in all other routes the variable is undefined:

```
// clock status
exports.clockStatus = function(req, res, next){
    var user = req.session.loggedIn;
    console.log('Status route, userID: '+user);
    if(user){
```

I found the answer in ["Cannot access req.session variables in Express/NodeJS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212828/cannot-access-req-session-variables-in-express-nodejs?rq=1)  but the last part trails off:

> In your case, you have assigned req.session.user = user; only in
>   /login request. It will not be available for further requests(/auth).
>
> You have to get user information in /auth request too by session id.
>   (Or) Better you can use passport for authentication.

HOW? How do you "get user information in /auth request too by session id"?

Please ask for anything else you need to straighten me out.
I'm stumped. I have tried some dumb stuff already!

Comment: What kind of browser are you using to visit the Express server?

Comment: Chrome is the browser of choice.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is undefined in other routes if you don't log in first in the browser. Here is my test code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');

app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'this is a test' }));

app.use(express.static(require('path').join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  req.session.uid = 'user001';
  res.send(req.session);
});


app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.session);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

First visit `http://localhost/login` in the browser. Then visit other URLs(e.g., `http://localhost/test`) in this browser, the user id in the session is returned. So maybe there is something wrong in other parts of your code.

Test settings:

- Ubuntu Desktop 13.10, 64 bit
- Node 0.10.26
- NPM 1.4.4
- Express 3.4.8
- cors 2.2.0