# Express.js - req.session variables are undefined in another controller

Tags: node.js, express

I know this question or similar was raised but I didn't find anything fitting to my case.

I've got login controller where I create session and its variables. Then in another controller (e.g. app.js) I want to check if user data were passed successfully. And... it's `undefined`. Session exists but not its variables.
Below I'm pasting some code, I hope it will clear up.

Why is this happening?

Note: `cookie: { secure: false }` is not working.

Edit: I've found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212828/cannot-access-req-session-variables-in-express-nodejs?rq=1) but is it possible to resolve this **without** using `Passport`?

#### login.js

```js
module.exports.login = (req, res) => {
    /*some login code */ 

    const loggedUserData = {
        id: userID,
        email: userEmail,
    };

    req.session.userData = loggedUserData;

    res.json({
        status: true,
        userData: req.session.userData,
    });

    console.log(req.session.userData.id); //it's defined
};
```

#### app.js

```js
module.exports.app = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.cookies["sid"]); //displays hash of session
    console.log(req.session.id); //also it has session id, it's fine
    console.log(req.session.userData); //but here is undefined
    console.log(req.session.userData.id); //and here it's blowing up because `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`
};
```

#### server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const loginController = require("./controllers/login");
const appController = require("./controllers/app");

const { PORT = 4001, NODE_ENV = "development", SESS_NAME = "sid", SESS_SECRET = "123", SESS_LIFETIME = null } = process.env;
const IN_PROD = NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false;

const app = express();
app.set("query parser", "simple");
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
app.use(express.static("./"));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "1mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
    session({
        secret: SESS_SECRET,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        name: SESS_NAME,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: true,
            secure: IN_PROD,
            maxAge: SESS_LIFETIME,
        },
    })
);
app.get("/", appController.app);
app.post("/login", loginController.login);

app.listen(PORT, () => `Server listening on ${PORT} port`);
```

Comment: it also doesn't work with the code that you're posting? (in other words, without the login code and hardcoded `loggedUserData`)

Comment: I assume the problem is between two different HTTP requests?  The first to "login" and the second for the "app"?  If so did you check the session persistence in between the two different calls? If not - are you sure those controllers are being called in the expected order?

Comment: @robertklep - What do you mean by "hardcoded `loggedUserData`"? Do you mean by putting login code directly into server.js file? If yes - should I place this code above `app.use(session({}))`?

Comment: @nymphais in my experience, a question with a comment stating _"some login code"_ instead of the actual code raises a bit of a red flag. So to rule out that the issue actually exists in that login code, using some hardcoded values could be used to check if that will persist in the session.

Comment: @akaphenom - Session persists everywhere, in every controller, but not its variables that I declared in login controller. 
I'm not sure in which order I should place calling controllers. For now ,as you can see, controllers are declared above `app.use(session())` and called below `app.use(session())`.

Comment: Is this across HTTP requests or in a single request?  If it is in a single request what order are the controllers hit?

Comment: @akaphenom - If I understand it correctly this is across many requests. When user is logging and it succeeds, it is sending `post` request handled by login controller. Then it is loading main page and it's checking if session exists and its variables (or when page is realoding) so it is executed `get` request handled by app controller.

Comment: Then I would check the session peristence (is it in a DB, or add logging to the session persistence) to see if the Login controller is doing what you think it is.

Comment: @robertklep - I see but the reason I presented code in this form is beacuse my current code is much more complicated and complex and I didn't want to show everything, only the clue of the problem. I was trying to outline the problem and I thought It will be enough to solve this.

Comment: @akaphenom - As I said before, `req.session` persists: e.g. when I `console.log()` in app controller or as a cookie in browser.

Comment: @nymphais you don't have to present your entire code here. I'm trying to say that to rule out the more complicated code, start with a basic example (much like the code you're posting here) to see if _that_ code also fails (because looking at what you're posting here, I don't see any obvious issues). If it doesn't, the issue is located somewhere in the code that you're not posting here. But from what you're saying, I assume that it's the particular code you're posting here that's failing already?