# req.body returning empty object when sending POST request from client side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, post

There are many questions related to the same topic but none of them solved my problem thats why asking new question

What I wanted to do is to send `POST` request from client side `javascript` to the `Backend` `NodeJs`

Client Side JS

```
const verifyOtp = async (otp) => {
  const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/otpVerify", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ otp: otp.value }),
  });

  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Backend Node js

```
const verifyOtp = router.post("/api/otpVerify", (req, res, next) => {
  const otp = req.body;

  console.log("Otp recieved: ", otp);
  console.log("Actual Otp: ", req.session.otp);
  if (otp == req.session.otp) {
    return res.json({ isVerified: true });
  }
  return res.json({ isVerified: false });
});
```

App.js File

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const session = require("express-session");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  session({ secret: "cezisbest", resave: false, saveUninitialized: false })
);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.set("views", "views");
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Content-Type, application/json"
  );
  next();
});

app.use("/api", userRoutes);
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

what I am getting Backend Node js file is an empty object Please help me with this error
`opt.value` is having a value which it is getting from frontend

in client side JS
on browser chrome it is displaying an object
`{isVerified:false}`

because the backend is unable to get data

Comment: You're returning an object with the otp keyword, which you can retrieve with `const { otp } = req.body `

Comment: How do you call `verifyOtp` on the frontend?

Comment: @MithatErcan I tried it then also its returning empty object

Comment: @KonradLinkowski its an just snippet of the code its used in an script.js file where I am getting otp value from input using querySelector

Comment: I guess that the parameter that you pass to this functions is `undefined`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No its not I have tried logging it to console its having an value

Comment: What does the `console.log("Otp recieved: ", otp);` prints?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it is printing an empty array {}

Comment: I guess that `otp.value` is `undefined`. I don't see any other way it could happen

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the `req.session.otp` value before calling `/api/otpVerify`. What is the reason you are using `req.session`?

`req.session` is basically gets cookies related information

Refer this:

> [Cannot access req.session variables in Express/NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212828/cannot-access-req-session-variables-in-express-nodejs)

Comment: I am actually using it to store correct otp and its value is given when the otp is sent

Comment: Then you must set the `req.session.otp = otp`

Comment: it is done in another function I did't included it here